# Expensive MeshRefinementFunction

Tags: performance-tuning, bugs, computational-geometry

I want to discretize a region using `DiscretizeRegion`. Now, I want the mesh to be more refined, when the curvature of a certain function `f` is larger than some fixed value, e.g.

```
DiscretizeRegion[
 Interval[{0, 1}],
 MeshRefinementFunction -> Function[{v, len},
   (* sample more points when curvature is large *)
   Abs@First@Differences[f /@ {v[[1]], Mean[v], v[[2]]}, 2] > 0.005
   ]
 ]
```

The problem is, that f is very expensive to evaluate. Therefore, I want to store all the generated values, so I can use them later. Naturally, I use the `MeshRefinementFunction` option, and `Sow` (and `Reap`) for this, but it doesn't work. As soon as `Sow` or `Print` appears in the function, MMA generates an error message and `DiscretizeRegion` does not evaluate. Here is a minimal example:

```
DiscretizeRegion[
  Interval[{0, 1}],
  MeshRefinementFunction -> (Sow@#2 > 0.1 &)
]
```

The messages are:

1. MeshRegion::dgcell: "The cell Line[{1,2}] is degenerate."
2. TriangulateMesh::fdmtd: "-- Message text not found -- (!(\"SubdivideBoundaryIntervals\"))"
3. DiscretizeRegion::drf: "DiscretizeRegion was unable to discretize the region Interval[{0,1}]."

Everything is fine as soon as you remove the `Sow`. I suspect, that DiscretizeRegion tries to compile this function... What can I do about this (except writing my own version of `DiscretizeRegion`)?

Comment: This does not seem right, I filed it as a bug. As a side note, the missing message text suggest that you are not using the latest Version (V10.3) That version has many improvements for Comp-Geom (though this issue seems to persists)

Comment: Ok, thank you @user21!

Comment: A note for anyone else with a MeshRefinementFunction that is expensive per vertex, memoization can be a big win, since any given vertex may be passed to the MRF multiple times. In my case, the number of unique vertices was 1/16 the total number of vertices passed to the MRF.

Answer (score 4):

This does not solve the problem, but provides some additional observations.

---

As

```
DiscretizeRegion[Interval[{0, 1}], MeshRefinementFunction -> (Echo@#2 > 0.01 &)]
```

or

```
DiscretizeRegion[Interval[{0, 1}], MeshRefinementFunction -> ((Print[#2]; #2 > 0.01) &)]
```

work without any error messages I conclude that `Reap` is used somewhere within `DiscretizeRegion` and therefore using `Sow` causes these error messages.

One could use

```
list = {}; 
DiscretizeRegion[Interval[{0, 1}], 
  MeshRefinementFunction -> ((AppendTo[list, #2]; #2 > 0.01) &)]
```

[image: Out1]

instead of `Sow`.

However, the resulting output differs from using

```
DiscretizeRegion[Interval[{0, 1}], MeshRefinementFunction -> (#2 > 0.01 &)]
```

[image: Out2]

and the print outs show that a default `0.05` is used irrespective of the specified value.

The same behavior can be observed when using

```
DiscretizeRegion[Line[{{0}, {1}}], 
  MeshRefinementFunction -> Function[{v, a}, Print[a]; a > 0.01]]
```

or

```
DiscretizeRegion[Interval[{0, 1}], MeshRefinementFunction -> ({##}[[2]] > 0.001 &)]
```

instead.

An error message that reveals that `Compile` is being used by `DiscretizeRegion` can be forced with

```
DiscretizeRegion[Interval[{0, 1}], MeshRefinementFunction -> (##[[2]] > 0.001 &)]
```

These problems seem to be absent for 2D regions:

```
Reap@DiscretizeRegion[Disk[], MeshRefinementFunction -> 
   Function[{vertices, area}, Sow[area] > 0.0005 (1 + 10 Norm[Mean[vertices]])]]
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment! Unfortunately, your code does not work properly on MMA 10.1: it does not produce any messages, but DiscretizeRegion now ignores the MeshRefinementFunction option completely. When you replace 0.1 by 0.01, you will see that you get different results with and without the AppendTo part. Or perhaps this is a bug in MMA 10.1 (which I am still using)? Does it work properly on MMA 10.3?

Comment: Also, it should not matter if they used Sow inside, especially when I use a unique tag, which I tried.

Comment: @user, `Echo[]` is a new function in 10.3, so your version won't have it. It is indeed bizarre that the thing still doesn't work even after adding a tagged `Sow[]`.

Comment: I was refering to the second code. So with `((AppendTo[list, #2]; #2 > 0.02) &)` `DiscretizeRegion` behaves as if `MeshRefinementFunction` was not specified, but with `((#2 > 0.02) &)` it works all fine.

Comment: @user251850 I edited my answer and tested it with `0.01`. It should work now properly.

Comment: @Karsten7. Thank you again! But now the list is not filled :-) This is not surprising, as the pure function that's supposed to append to the list just stays a pure function that does not evaluate.

Comment: @J.M. Using a tag for `Sow` doesn't make a difference, when no tag was used for the hypothetical `Reap` inside `DiscretizeRegion`. For example, try `Reap[Reap[Sow[x, "tag00"]];]` and `Reap[Reap[Sow[x, "tag00"], "noTag"];]`.

Comment: Very true. I didn't think of that. However, the AppendTo (or Print) issues still persist.